# Understanding how initializing the Ledger Bitcoin hardware wallet works

Tags: ledger-hardware-wallet

One can find the Ledger Bitcoin source code here:

https://github.com/LedgerHQ/app-bitcoin

I am trying to understand how a Ledger app account is initialized or restored.

Can someone point me to another 'official' project, which is communicating with this Ledger firmware?
Wallets typically have user functionality to initialize or restore a wallet. I am interested in how this is mapped or delegated to the hardware device.

I am interested in the parts where APDU commands are sent to the device to initialize or restore the device.

Sorry if this question is vague, or contains factual errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ledger provides a python library which also links to some limited documentation of the API: https://github.com/ledgerhq/btchip-python